# prototype cleanWhitespace() is not working for inserted items

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm adding a new element into OL list using prototype. In order to use .firstChild property I'm using a cleanWhitespace() function before doing anything. This is working quite nice and if I'm tracing innerHTML of my OL after it is just a plain string as expected.

Then I'm adding a new LI item and it is added with whitespaces. Applying cleanWhitespace() function after adding new LI is not making any effect. Any ideas why?

Here is my bit of code:

```
$$('div.pagination > ol').each(function(item){
    item.cleanWhitespace(); // Working
    if(!item.firstChild.childElementCount) {
        var prevLi = document.createElement('li');
        prevLi.update('<a href="#">&laquo;</a>');
        prevLi.addClassName('disabled');
        item.insertBefore(prevLi, item.firstChild);
    }else{
        item.firstChild.children[0].update('&laquo;');
    }
    item.cleanWhitespace(); // Not working
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand why you're using `cleanWhitespace` here, but if it's only to use `firstChild` to not hit any text nodes, I'd definitely forego all that and just use [Element#firstDescendant](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/firstDescendant/) as it skips text and comment nodes. All of Prototype's DOM traversal methods (`descendants`, `immediateDescendants`, etc) skip the garbage you don't want.

Comment: I'm using `cleanWhitespace` exactly to clean whitespace. My `li` elements have `display:inline-block` so I need no whitespace between them. Thus your answer makes no sense. Sorry.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with relevant css and html? I don't think we're getting the whole picture here.